# Flatpak installation contradiction?

Tags: apt, flatpak

After believing that I had installed flatpak successfully on Ubuntu 20.04, when I tried to install a package on it, I eventually received an error message telling me that I needed the latest version of flatpak, ie 1.8.2. I have version 1.6.5. So I did a `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` but still find that am stuck on flatpak v. 1.6.5.

How do I install the latest version?

Comment: Add output of `apt-cache policy flatpak`. 1.6.5 is [normal](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/flatpak) for official Ubuntu 20.04 LTS repository.

Comment: @N0rbert Pretty well. Do I need to remove the Focal one first before installing from the Larsen ppa?

Comment: No, APT will do package version upgrade for you.